# Setting domain and range of a property

Tags: rdf, semantics, owl, ontology

I have two classes (i.e., Observation and Sensor) and an object property (i.e., observedBy) in my SSN ontology.So, the required scenario is like this:
[image]
*Observation* class in protege is presented as:
[image]

and *observedBy* property is presented as:
[image]

Now the question is, do I need to specify the Domain and Range of observedBy property as both of these fields are empty as shown in third picture. But, while looking at observation class in picture 2, I find that it is associated with statements "*observedBy only Sensor"* and "o*bservedBy exactly 1 sensor*". By these statements I infer that I donot need to mention domain and range of observedBy property. Am I right in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to, but that depends on how you want to model your knowledge base. The cardinality constraint (`observedBy exactly 1 Sensor` in the figure) looks like a restriction set on the `Observation` class, as in:

```
:Observation rdfs:subClassOf 
   [ a owl:Restriction;
     owl:onProperty :observedBy;
     owl:minCardinality 1;
     owl:maxCardinality 1 ]
```

Setting the rdfs `domain` and `range` of `observedBy` you will in essence restrict the use of the property, which may be something you want to do, or not.

Comment: As a personal opinion, I assume that OP is developing an ontology for a specific domain, and since it's intended for a specific domain, it's probably reasonable to use the domain and range properties rather than something like "observation subclassof observedBy only Sensor" (unless there are other uses of the property within ontology).  My reason being that someone asserting "x sensorOntology:observedBy y" is consciously using sensorOntology, and should be aware of the intended use of the property.  So why not use the simpler domain/range reasoning that will work even in RDFS?

Comment: Totally agree. Simplicity is a virtue. In my answer I have only explained what the restriction is that is showing up in the editor. Fine-graining semantics is really a matter of opinion/modelling, but the presence of domain/range axioms is something that we've all come to expect, perhaps as a bare minimum. There are also reasoning/inference implications behind both axioms, although I don't think that's something of concern here.

Comment: @chris  Can I infer from your discussion that for simplicity: if the required property is added as a restriction to a class, then I should not add explicitly the domain and range of said property. Also, if I add the domain and range to a property in spite of it added as a restriction that will not create any problem.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor  Can I infer from your discussion that for simplicity: if the required property is added as a restriction to a class, then I should not add explicitly the domain and range of said property. Also, if I add the domain and range to a property in spite of it added as a restriction that will not create any problem.

Comment: My advice is to set the domain/range and other property-level semantics (e.g. whether functional or inverse functional) of 'observedBy' and all other locally-defined properties. Probably nothing will break if you don't, but it is a generally good practise to do so. Your model will be less ambiguous and easier for someone to detect the intended use of your properties. If you require fine tuning your model on a per class basis then you may look beyond simple property definitions. Hope this helps.